# Searching full terms against document with wildcards elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, wildcard

I have indexed documents with wildcards:

For example:

```
_source: {
  "keyword": "*ower"
}
```

Now I want to search with full term and find matching:

For instance:

```
"match": {
   "keyword": "tower"
}
```

Should match the initial document.
How can I do that with Elasticsearch? Do I need a special analyzer for that?

Note that it's exactly like wildcard query but works the opposite way (the wildcard is in the document and not in the searched term).

Comment: Why do you want to do that and why not indexing the normal words and afterwards using wildcards when searching?

Comment: Imagine I want to store a set of valid terms (that includes wuldcards) as es documentss. Then, given a variable fulltext, i want to find which terms were found in it (for later analysis).